# Same style for input submit control as @html.ActionLink

Tags: html, css

I am looking to obtain the same style for both @html.ActionLink & a input submot control (both buttons) on a form. I basically want the input control to look the same the ActionLink control.

```
<div class="btn btn-success">
       @Html.ActionLink("RSVP Now", "RsvpForm")
</div>
```

[image]

```
<div class="btn btn-success">
   <input type="submit" value="Update RSVP" />
</div>
```

[image]

I want the bottom button to look the above button

(btn btn-sucess is from the bootstrap library)

Comment: what's the markup received on the browser (view source) from the first snippet?

Comment: copy class of above button by Inspect Element and assign it to below button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div>
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Update RSVP" />
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing.....thanks! p.s. I will mark as correct but SO doesn't let you until a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the class inside the HTML Attributes parameter of the Html.ActionLink Method.

```
<div>
       @Html.ActionLink("RSVP Now", "RsvpForm", new{@class="btn btn-success"})
</div>
```